# Pure JS to ReactJS in slick-slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I am trying to make this code

```
if (currentSlide === 0) {
  $('.slick-prev').hide();
  $('.slick-next').show();
}
else {
    $('.slick-prev').show();
}

//If we're on the last slide hide the Next button.
if (slick.slideCount === currentSlide + 1) {
    $('.slick-next').hide();
}
```

work within the **React** version of [slick carousel](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick). Can someone point me in the right direction?

The code is to hide and display the arrows of [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) when on the first and last slide of the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `afterChange` callback to set the state of the component and put an empty div as the nextArrow.
It will look something like that for the nextArrow, I think you will see how to implement it for the prevArrow also: (Don't forget to bind the function in the constructor)

```
onIndexChange(index){
  this.setState({index});
}

 <Slider afterChange={this.onIndexChange} 
         nextArrow={this.state.index === 5 ? <div></div>:null}>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </Slider>
```